# Custom NSViewController container

Tags: cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a custom container view controller, that will transition between the views of the child view controllers.

My thinking was to add an initial subview (childviewcontroller) to the parent controller, then use

> - transitionFromViewController:toViewController:options:completionHandler

to transition between views, so I currently have a method that looks like this

```
func selectTabAtIndex(index: Int) {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < childViewControllers.count, "index out of range")
    for (i, button) in buttons.enumerate() {
        button.state = (index == i) ? NSOnState : NSOffState
    }
    let viewController = childViewControllers[index]

    if let presentedViewController = presentedViewControllers?.last {
        transitionFromViewController(presentedViewController, toViewController: viewController, options: .Crossfade, completionHandler: {log.info("Completed Transition")})
    } else {

        self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)

        viewController.view.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(stackView.snp_right)
            make.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.right.equalTo(self.view)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view)
        }
    }
}
```

However, the presentedViewControllers array is always empty, despite having a child view controller view previously added as a subview. So, transitionFromViewController never gets called.

How do you set the initial presented view controller of the parent controller?